# Troubleshooting downloading MODIS NDVI Data in R

Tags: r, tiles, modis, ndvi, evi

I am trying to download MODIS Data from 2000-2018, however I am encountering some difficulties.

Here is my script

```
         MODISoptions(localArcPath = "/Volumes/myserver/MODIS/data", 
         outDirPath = "/Volumes/myserver/MODIS/data/proc_data")
         runGdal("MOD13A2", collection = "006", # see getCollection("MOD13Q1", forceCheck = TRUE)
         tileH = 8, tileV = 7, # MODIS tile id
         begin = "2000.02.18", end = "2018.03.31", # time period
         SDSstring = "110000000000") # SDS layers to extract (here: NDVI, EVI)
```

I am trying to do multiple dates from H: 6-8, and V: 7-9. However, when I run it, the program downloads several tiles then encounters this error:

```
   "Username/Password Authentication Failed.
   Remote connection failed! Re-try: 1 Getting file from: LAADS 
   trying URL 'ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/6/MOD13A2/2000/353/MOD13A2.A2000353.h08v07.006.2017285143550.hdf' 
   Content type 'unknown' length 7085835 bytes (6.8 MB)
   Downloaded after: 2 re-tries 
   Error in load(fls_col) : empty (zero-byte) input file"
```

How do I get around this?

I believe it to be a missing tile, and the code terminating instead of skipping it, and going to the next one.

Comment: Which package are you using? You can download MODIS scenes with `rst` and `MODIS` packages

Comment: I am just using the MODIS package.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODIS/index.html

Comment: Did you tried with `getHdf`?

Comment: Strongly recommend using MODIStsp for downloading and handling MODIS data, see: https://github.com/lbusett/MODIStsp

Answer (score 1):

[LAADS FTP is deprecated](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/alerts-and-issues/?id=23707) and its data moved to HTTPS. Use **MODIS_1.1.3** (or higher) which covers this important migration. With this package version, your code runs smoothly on my machine.

```
library(MODIS)

tfs = runGdal("MOD13A2", collection = "006", 
              tileH = 8, tileV = 7, 
              begin = "2000.02.18", end = "2000.03.10", 
              SDSstring = "110000000000") # extract NDVI and EVI
tfs
# $`MOD13A2.006`
# $`MOD13A2.006`$`2000-02-18`
# [1] "../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/MOD13A2.006_20180912132721/MOD13A2.A2000049.1_km_16_days_NDVI.tif"
# [2] "../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/MOD13A2.006_20180912132721/MOD13A2.A2000049.1_km_16_days_EVI.tif" 
# 
# $`MOD13A2.006`$`2000-03-05`
# [1] "../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/MOD13A2.006_20180912132721/MOD13A2.A2000065.1_km_16_days_NDVI.tif"
# [2] "../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/MOD13A2.006_20180912132721/MOD13A2.A2000065.1_km_16_days_EVI.tif"
```

For further details and download alternatives (ie. get data from [LP DAAC](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/) using Earthdata login credentials), please check out my answers to the following SO questions:

- [Download MODIS/MCD19A2 AOD product with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295080/download-modis-mcd19a2-aod-product-with-r)
- and [MODIS R Connection error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283164/modis-r-connection-error).