# Download MODIS/MCD19A2 AOD product with R

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis, api

I'm looking for a programmatic way to download [MODIS/MCD19A2 AOD](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mcd19a2_v006) data in R. So far, I've found a pretty solid R package called [MODISTools](https://github.com/ornldaac/modis_restservice_qc_filter_R/blob/master/modis_restservice_qc_filter_R.ipynb) that works nicely with the [MODIS/VIIRS RESTful API](https://modis.ornl.gov/data/modis_webservice.html). However, this web service does not provide access to the AOD product that I need (MCD19A2). Currently, the only way I know of downloading the AOD product is manually via the [Nasa EarthData Search](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search) tool, or via the [NASA Data Pool](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD19A2.006/).

Is there anyone out there that has found a more convenient and programmatic way to work with the MCD19A2 AOD product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using the **MODIS** package, version **1.1.3** or higher (previous versions didn't provide access to this product).

```
library(MODIS)

# set MODIS options (these can also be passed to '...' in getHdf())
MODISoptions(localArcPath = "OutputDestinationFolder", quiet = FALSE)

# download data
hdf = getHdf("MCD19A2", collection = "006"
             , tileH = 9, tileV = 4
             , begin = "2018.08.28", end = "2018.08.31")
hdf
# $`MCD19A2.006`
# [1] "OutputDestinationFolder/MODIS/MCD19A2.006/2018.08.28/MCD19A2.A2018240.h09v04.006.2018242043359.hdf"
# [2] "OutputDestinationFolder/MODIS/MCD19A2.006/2018.08.29/MCD19A2.A2018241.h09v04.006.2018250043019.hdf"
# [3] "OutputDestinationFolder/MODIS/MCD19A2.006/2018.08.30/MCD19A2.A2018242.h09v04.006.2018250043020.hdf"
# [4] "OutputDestinationFolder/MODIS/MCD19A2.006/2018.08.31/MCD19A2.A2018243.h09v04.006.2018250043021.hdf"
```

This downloads all .hdf files found for the specified tile indices and time frame and puts them in the desired target folder. You might also use `runGdal()` instead to download *and* extract the data in one go, provided that GDAL is available. This renders unnecessary an explicit call to `getHdf()`.

```
tfs = runGdal("MCD19A2", collection = "006"
              , tileH = 9, tileV = 4
              , begin = "2018.08.28", end = "2018.08.31"
              , job = "MCD19A2", SDSstring = "1010000000000")
tfs
# $`MCD19A2.006`
# $`MCD19A2.006`$`2018-08-28`
# [1] "OutputDestinationFolder/PROCESSED/MCD19A2/MCD19A2.A2018240.Optical_Depth_047.tif"
# [2] "OutputDestinationFolder/PROCESSED/MCD19A2/MCD19A2.A2018240.AOD_Uncertainty.tif"  
# 
# $`MCD19A2.006`$`2018-08-29`
# [1] "OutputDestinationFolder/PROCESSED/MCD19A2/MCD19A2.A2018241.Optical_Depth_047.tif"
# [2] "OutputDestinationFolder/PROCESSED/MCD19A2/MCD19A2.A2018241.AOD_Uncertainty.tif"  
# ...
```

For further information, see also

- `?getProduct()` for a list of available products;
- `getProduct("MCD19A2")` for details on a paricular product;
- argument 'outDirPath' in `?MODISoptions()` to specify a target folder for extracted layers;
- and arguments 'dlmethod' and 'dataFormat' in `?MODISoptions()` for supported download methods and write formats, respectively.

Comment: Are you using a dev version of the MODIS package? Right now I'm unable to download the MCD19A2 data with `getHdf()` or `runGdal()`. Also, `getProduct("MCD19A2")` produces the following error: `No product found with the name MCD19A2.`.

Comment: **MODIS_1.1.3** hit CRAN only yesterday. I am using this version; it includes a set of newly introduced products as well as snow and ice cover datasets from [NSIDC](https://nsidc.org/), which haven't been available before.

Comment: Installing **MODIS_1.1.3** solved my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're very welcome! I also added the required version to my answer. If you should encounter any difficulties, bugs, etc., please feel free to report back to https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS/issues - we're thankful for any additional input.

Answer (score 3):

Okay after a bit of digging, I've figured out how to download MCD19A2 AOD data using `wget` and R!

I've created a basic R function that downloads all `.hdf` files for a given date based on the specified MODIS tile. If you are a linux user and have a NASA EarthData account, then the following code should also work for you!

```
getAOD <- function(user = 'EarthDataUsername'
               ,pw = 'EarthDataPassword'
               ,dir = 'OutputDestinationFolder'
               ,product = 'MCD19A2' # default product for MAIAC AOD
               ,date = '2018.08.28' # day of interest
               ,tile = 'h09v04' # your tile id (depends on your location)
               ,collection = "006") {

  # parse date and julian date for url building
  Date <- lubridate::ymd(date)
  julianDate <- paste0(lubridate::year(Date)
                   ,lubridate::yday(Date))

  # extracts hdf files for a given tile across all observation times
  pattern <- paste0(product, ".A", julianDate, ".", tile, ".", collection, "*.hdf")

  # base url for wget
  url <- paste0("https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/", product, ".", collection, "/", date, "/")

  # call wget from command line
  system(paste0("wget -r -A", pattern, " -L --user=", user
            ," --password=", pw
            ," --directory-prefix=", dir
            ," --load-cookies ~/.cookies --save-cookies ~/.cookies ", url))

}
```

I keep my EarthDataPassword in a file called `batteries.dppss`. I then scan this while calling the `getAOD()` function.

```
getAOD(user = 'myUserName'
    ,pw = scan("./batteries.dppss", what = "")
    ,dir = "./test")
```

Comment: I have tried this method and got an error message of "Cannot open cookies file '~/.cookies': No such file or directory". Just wondering what is the cookies used for?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `wget` installed, or prefer not to rely on system calls, see https://github.com/AustralianAntarcticDivision/blueant/issues/11. It's very similar to your code, but the recursive downloading all happens in R, not `wget`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm still trying to get `bowerbird` installed/configured, but I'm interested in comparing the run times between this and `wget`.

Comment: Run times will almost certainly be faster with `wget`