# Convenient way to download MCD19A2 product using R

Tags: r, modis, download

I want to download MODIS MCDA219 product. I have been downloading manually from

1. https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/
2. and https://earthdata.nasa.gov .

As a new to R user, recently I have learn downloading this product using R with help of ***[Download MODIS/MCD19A2 AOD product with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295080/download-modis-mcd19a2-aod-product-with-r?newreg=e5982d639fa64a8e921c38063547ef96) .*** 
Problem is, the daily product are creating too much folder. For example if I try to download January month of 2018, then it will create folder for each day. So for January month, 31 hdf format files are in 31 folders each. How can I download MCD19A2 product by month and the HDF file?
I will need more than 50,000 dataset and I was looking for more convenient way to download the product using R

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
install.packages("MODIStsp")
library(MODIStsp)
MODIStsp()
```

It's a good GUI to download and process MODIS data.

Comment: The MODIStsp package does not include this product.

Answer (score 0):

the library `rts` might help be of your help. It contains almost all MODIS products and allows you to download, mosaic and reproject MODIS data all within the download command. You can have a unique GeoTIFF for each date as an output, which might reduce the number of file you have to store. Try

```
install.packages('rts')
library(rts)
modisProducts() # this shows all products available with this library
```

to make sure the product you need is available (very likely). The download process is not as straightforward, as it requires authenticating with NASA which in turn requires previous authentication. This process is described in detail [here](http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rts/rts.pdf).

Comment: my product 'MCD19A2' is not listed there.